# Separating css image properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 images of an arrow I would like to add to a CSS class (up, down, right, left).

I created a basic arrow css class:

```
.arrow {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

and then created subclasses e.g:

```
.arrow .up {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow-up.png");
}
arrow .down {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow-down.png");
}
```

When I add both classes to a table cell (with jQuery) it doesn't show the image.
The thing is that if I combine them into 1 class, e.g.

```
.arrow-up {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow-up.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

and then add it to the table cell it works just fine.

How can I avoid repeating the "background-repeat" and "background-position" in every class?

Comment: Assuming the class on your image is `"arrow up"`, your css selector needs to be `.arrow.up`. The way you have it now matches elements with the class `up` which are descendants of elements with the class `arrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code will be:

```
.arrow {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.arrow.up {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow-up.png");
}
.arrow.down {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow-down.png");
}

<td class="arrow up">
 Content
</td>
```